# SSL Certificate: Signature Algorithm shows "sha256rsa" but thumbprint algorithm shows "sha1"

Tags: algorithm, security, ssl-certificate, rsa, sha

I have a certificate where Signature Algorithm shows "sha256rsa" but thumbprint algorithm shows"sha1". What will be the identification of my certicate **SHA1/SHA2**?

Thanks!

Comment: @PaulBastide I don't believe that's relevant. There's no sha2/sha256 confusion here.

Comment: It would be great if you provided some more information. How are you getting those descriptions about the cert? (the signature algorithm/thumbprint may mean various things) What do you mean by "what will be the identification"? Is it related to browsers deprecating sha1? It may be also useful if you posted the certificate itself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

TL;TR: signature and thumbprint are totally different things. For strength of the certificate thumbprint is irrelevant but signature is relevant.

The signature of a certificate is the thing the issuer creates by signing the certificate. This signature is used by the TLS stack (inside the browser) to validate the trust chain. It is important to use a strong algorithm here so that nobody can create a fake certificate which looks like it was signed by a trusted issuer (CA).

The thumbprint is just a hash over the certificate. It is mainly intended for human reception, i.e. check that the certificate is the intended one. This is usually used with self-signed certificates where the browser can not validate the certificate by itself since there is no trusted issuer and so the user should verify the certificate manually against the expected one.

A certificate has only a single signature since it has only a single issuer. But you often find multiple thumbprints for the certificate, i.e. one with MD5, one with SHA-1 and one with SHA-256. This is because the browser does not know which one you got for manual verification and that's why it offers you the most common versions.

> What will be the identification of my certicate SHA1/SHA2?

The identification is the certificate itself, i.e. neither the signature not the thumbprint. But if you mean the "this certificate was signed with ...." part than this is SHA-256 in your case since what counts is the signature and not some thumbprint.